# Add column and set value

Tags: mysql, locking, alter

I need to add a new column NOT NULL whose value should be proportional to other field. Now the proportion is the same, but in the future could be diferent

By now my current script

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN (basePrice FLOAT(10,2) NULL);
UPDATE myTable set basePrice = 0,9 * price;
ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY COLUMN (basePrice FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL);
```

but I would like to know if there is a way to do this in a single query in order to reduce the required time and avoid locks.

Comment: Note that things to do with money are not usually FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented.

Comment: Probably I would do this using a view or a trigger

Answer (score 4):

Several things to note:

This gets rid of one of the `ALTERs:`

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN basePrice FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
UPDATE myTable set basePrice = 0,9 * price;
```

MySQL 8.0 can add a column essentially instantly.  (There would still need to be the `UPDATE`.

`pt-online-schema-change` can do the task with virtually zero lock time.

The `UPDATE` can (should) be done in chunks of, say, 1000 rows.  Each chunk would be its own transaction.  This minimizes locks during the update.  More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) .

(And I strongly agree with Strawberry about using `DECIMAL(8,2)` (or whatever size) for money.)

MySQL 5.7 can have a "generated" column, but I suspect it will not buy you anything since you expect to change the formula later.